# What does 装卸 mean here?

Tags: meaning

My sentence is:

未来商店的购物车把手上装有购物助手----一个可随意装卸的无线电脑工具。

装卸的意思是: load-unload, transfer, assemble-disassemble

Maybe here '装卸‘ just means the 购物助手 'can be mounted on the shopping trolley if you wish'.

Or does 随意装卸的无线电脑‘ mean here 'the wireless computer can be freely programmed'?

In that case 装卸 means 'program, upload any data, transfer data to'?

Answer (score 3):

- 购物助手(shopping helper) is the topic
- 一个可随意装卸的无线电脑工具。'*a wireless computer tool (device) that can be mounted and dismounted at will.*'  is the comment on the topic. It explains what 购物助手 is.

Since 购物助手 is a device, 装卸(mount/dismount) here refers to the mounting and dismounting of the unit itself--  nothing to do with data upload and download.

By the way:

- 'Data **upload** and **download**' in Chinese would be '数据(data)**上传**(up load)和**下载**(down load)'.
- Not '数据(data)**装上**(load up)和**卸下**(unload)'

Answer (score 1):

> 一个可随意装卸的无线电脑工具

The most important point to Wireless Computer Tools is that the tools don't need any wire to link with Shopping Cart. So they may link with each other through WiFi, Bluetooth or other wireless technology.

The linking progress is like that you link your Smartphone with computer or disconnect your phone from computer. So 装卸 means the linking progress that I said.

Comment: Now I have a contradiction: You say it is " the linking progress" that is, link in to the 无线系统 , Tang Ho says "装卸(mount/dismount)"， that is 'physically put the 无线电脑 on the shopping trolley. How to decide? Do you have any more arguments for your interpretation?

Comment: @Pedroski Depends on your scenario. This word could be used in virtual bodies like software or physical device.

Comment: @Pedroski Actually, if you say that the 一个可随意装卸的无线电脑工具 could be 装卸（mount/dismount) on  physical 购物车把手上, it also makes sense. So this sentence is ambiguous. How to understand this sentence depends on yourself or the context.